Can't connect to local SQL Server when running app through Docker container
I'm trying to run my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API through Docker, this is my first time ever using Docker with .NET and it's being a headache.
When I run the API through Container (Dockerfile), this code is run to migrate the database, if needed:
public static class DataHelper
{
    public static async Task ManageDataAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using AppDbContext db = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

        IEnumerable<String> pendingMigrationIds = await db.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (pendingMigrationIds.Any())
        {
            await db.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}

However when I run the code, this exception is thrown on .GetPendingMigrations:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

So I went on SO and tried these solutions:

Opened the SQL Server Configuration and enabled Shared Memory, Named Pipes & TCP/IP on both MSSQLServer & SQLExpress, added TCP Port's IPALL to 1433.
Opened Win+r with services.msc and restarted SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) & SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) as well as their Server Agent.
I've changed my connection strings to use Data Source=<IP>,<PORT>;..., Data Source=Data Source=local\\MSSQLLocalDB;..., Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;..., Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;... but nothing works
I restarted the PC
I deleted the containers and images before redoing everything again

Here’s my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081


# This stage is used to build the service project
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyAPI/MyAPI.csproj", "MyAPI/"]

COPY ["Application/Application.csproj", "Application/"]
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
COPY ["Persistence/Persistence.csproj", "Persistence/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./MyAPI/MyAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyAPI"
RUN dotnet build "./MyAPI.csproj" -c     
$BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

# This stage is used to publish the service project to be copied to the final stage
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./MyAPI.csproj" -c     
$BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# This stage is used in production or when running from VS in regular mode (Default when not using the Debug configuration)
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPI.dll"]

I tried every solution I could find on SO but nothing worked.
How can I connect to SQL Server from Docker ?

Add your docker compose file or dockerfile + commands.

Is sql server also inside docker or is it on your host? Usually localdb won't work at all, while stuff like localhost points inside docker and not inside host, so you need to adjust your connection string to use docker.host.local or whatever. Named instance need to have some port opened (1434 for the discovery)

If the database you are trying to access is on your local machine and you are trying to run a web server inside a docker container to access that database, you can use "--network=host" when running the docker instance to allow access to localhost. This is more a work-around for initial testing. Ultimately if your database will be on a dedicated server/image you need to configure both the docker instance outbound connectivity and the database server/instance inbound connectivity to expect one another.

Docker images generally don't have the same IP ranges as the machine/environment that host them so default/standard connectivity rules for databases and other services might not accept requests from containers, and Docker itself I believe wants to sandbox communications to between images by default.

@Mate I’ve added the Dockerfile

LocalDB is a Windows-only technology that relies on Windows/AD authentication as well as the Named Pipes protocol. I'm afraid you can't use that from Docker.

@StevePy should I then just configure the actual production SQL server I need and make Docker connect to it instead of wasting my time with the local environment ?

If you have a full SQL Server instance (Enterprise, Standard, Developer, Express)... from a networking perspective Docker containers are their own little Linux VMs and localhost, 127.0.0.1 and ::1 all refer to the container itself. If you have a network service listening on the Docker host itself (or even published on a host's port from another Docker container) have you tried using host.docker.internal instead? e.g.: Server=host.docker.internal,1433;...

@AlwaysLearning I want to try your technique but how would I have a "network service listening on the Docker host itself " ?

You say this was working previously... so do you have SQL Server installed or not? To have remote processes connect it must have ports listening, i.e.: network services.

Thx, You could try using a container with ms-sql docker img like : mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest  .  ex: https://medium.com/@zzpzaf.se/ms-sql-server-in-docker-b0397a55859c   . Then if you could connect from some IDE to your ms-sql container. You could connect from anywhere.

@CodingIsFunYouShouldTryIt Ultimately it doesn't make that much of a difference. Connecting to your local machine from a docker instance is basically no different to connecting to another server, or instance in a different container. You have to explicitly configure both sides to ensure the caller can "see" the destination, and the destination accepts requests from that instance/container. Most of what you need is covered here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/network/  Basically treat container images as isolated networks. Any interconnectivity needs to be explicitly setup.

@AlwaysLearning it was working when I was just running it without Docker with Visual Studio 2022

@CodingIsFunYouShouldTryIt just running it without Docker isn't "just". You haven't installed SQL Server LocalDB in the container. LocalDB, an embedded database that's hosted and run by your own application. You're trying to use it  inside the aspnet container which contains only the ASP.NET Core runtime. You haven't added anything that installs LocalDB

@CodingIsFunYouShouldTryIt BTW I see people already explained this earlier. If you want to connect to a database on the host, you have to use a proper SQL Server or SQL Server Express instance and use host.docker.internal. Another option is to run SQL Server on a separate container and configure the network connection between them, eg using Docker Compose. Check Tutorial: Create a multi-container app with Docker Compose. In Data Source use the name of the SQL container

@PanagiotisKanavos I see, so you can't use the conventional "SQL Server Explorer" tab way with Docker there's just a different way to do it right ?
